# Issues with ElasticSearch wildcard filter and hyphenated text

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-appsync, amazon-opensearch

I am using ElasticSearch as part of AWS OpenSearch. I am using the AppSync query builder to apply a `wildcard:` filter on a date field with the format `2023-07-28T16:19:23.196Z`. I am interested in returning matches which share the year, date, time `2023-07-28` portion of this date format.

When executing a query with the following filter, all entries in the year 2023 are returned (as expected).

```
query MyQuery {
  search(filter: {date_needed_by: {wildcard: "2023*"}}) {
    ...
  }
}
```

However, when I add the month and day into the filter like so, it fails to return any results, despite the matching entries being present.

```
query MyQuery {
  search(filter: {date_needed_by: {wildcard: "2023-07-28*"}}) {
    ...
  }
}
```

This issue persists even if the hyphens are replaced with `*` or `?` operators. I am at a loss for the cause of this behavior and have found no help in the documentation. Many thanks in advance.